# camera_calibration package not detected and cannot locate rosdep definition for sensor_msgs

Tags: calibration, kinect, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte

I downloaded the camera_calibration package using

git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline.git

When I do

rosdep install camera_calibration

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
camera_calibration: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [sensor_msgs]

rosmake camera_calibration

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['camera_calibration']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/sai/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130514-164830
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['camera_calibration'] to:
['camera_calibration']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> camera_calibration [ make ]
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< camera_calibration ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration
No Makefile in package camera_calibration
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 3 packages with 0 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/sai/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130514-164830
sai@sai-HP-EliteBook-8460w:~/fuerte_workspace$

finally when i do roscd camera_calibration

roscd: No such package/stack 'camera_calibration'

***There is no issue with sensor_msgs and is working well

Any help on how to solve these issues and get camera_calibration to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62673/camera_calibration-package-not-detected-and-cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-sensor_msgs/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on 2013-05-13**:
This means ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not set properly and hence ROS is unable to locate sensor_msgs and camera_calibration packages. Are you using a ros workspace or are you installing in some directory. In the latter case, are you setting the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to include that directory as well?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-14**:
Hi, I am using ROS workspace and am able to roscd to sensor_msgs and all the issues are solved with camera_calibration...Only one thing  is left..when I do                                rosdep install camera_calibration it says camera_calibration: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [sensor_msgs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will be much simpler to just install the Ubuntu package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-image-pipeline
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-14**:
Hi, I tried this and now I am struck with one thing .when I do rosdep install camera_calibration                    it says           camera_calibration: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [sensor_msgs]

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-15**:
The point of using apt-get was to *avoid* building image-pipeline from source. Common messages should have been installed automatically, they are a dependency. You should not need that `rosdep install`.

**Comment by [Sulphur](https://answers.ros.org/users/31675/sulphur/) on 2017-09-12**:
@sai @joq Hey. I have the same problem and it isn't yet solved.
For "sudo apt-get install camera_calibration", I am getting "Unable to locate package camera_calibration"

For "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-image-pipeline", I am getting Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-image-pipeline

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-10-03**:
This answer dates back to 2013. ROS Fuerte is no longer supported. Substitute the name of the ROS version you are actually running.